# Paint doesnt seem to be painting things

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying tp paint an image of a cheetah just to mess around with the paint method and such, but it doesn't seem to be working, any idea why?

I've tried a ton of stuff i found on here but nothing seems toi work at all, all i get is my button, i know its the actual paint method not working because it doesn't even pain the Hello string.

Here's the main class:

```
package dev.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import dev.angora.gui.GameGUI;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static JFrame p = new JFrame("Angora Realms");

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new Main();

    }

    public Main() {

        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.pack();
        p.setSize(640, 800);
        p.setVisible(true);
        p.setLayout(null);

        GameGUI g = new GameGUI();
        g.createGui(p);

    }

}
```

And here is the class I try to paint in:

```
package dev.gui;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public Button drawCard = new Button("Draw Card");
    public Image cheetah = null;

    public void createGui(JFrame p) {

        drawCard.addActionListener(this);
        drawCard.setBounds(20,30,80,30);
        p.add(drawCard);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        Object cause = event.getSource();

        if (cause == drawCard) {
        System.out.println("Ay");
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Hello", 200, 50);
        if (cheetah == null) {
        cheetah = getImage("plains/Cheetah.png");
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawImage(cheetah, 100, 100, 100, 300, this);
        }
    }

    public Image getImage(String path) {

        Image tempImage = null;
        try {
            URL imageURL = GameGUI.class.getResource(path);
            tempImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured -" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return tempImage;

    }
} '
```

Comment: Hint: the JFrame with the paintComponent is not the JFrame you're displaying on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're creating something like three `JFrame`s, so it's kind of hard to track where things are actually going.  There is no need to use `extends JFrame` for either of the two classes you presented, in fact, this will highlight the cause of your error...
2. `JFrame` does not have a `paintComponent` method, so it will never be called, instead, change `GameGUI` to extend from `JPanel` and add `@Override` to the start of the `paintComponent` method declaration (before it), then change `super.paint(g);` to `super.paintComponent(g);`

For example...

```
public class GameGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public Button drawCard = new Button("Draw Card");
    public Image cheetah = null;

    public void createGui(JFrame p) {

        drawCard.addActionListener(this);
        drawCard.setBounds(20,30,80,30);
        p.add(drawCard);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        Object cause = event.getSource();

        if (cause == drawCard) {
        System.out.println("Ay");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
```

No offense, but I'm not a fan of passing a reference of the "container" to the child component so it can add itself in this way.  Better to create an instance of `GameGUI` and add it to what ever container you want.  The `GameGUI` doesn't need to know or care...IMHO

**Runnable Example**

- Don't use `pack` and `setSize`, they are competing with each other.  The content of the frame should dictate the size of the frame.  This is done through the use of appropriate layout managers and overriding `getPreferredSize` of custom components.
- Don't call `setVisible` until AFTER you've established the base UI
- Make sure you are adding your components to a displayable surface if you expect them to be painted

[image]

Also, you're mixing heavy weight (`java.awt.Button`) and light weight (Swing/`javax.swing.JFrame`) components together...my recommendation is, don't, this will cause a bunch of other issues you really don't need to deal with.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Main();

    }

    public Main() {

        JFrame p = new JFrame("Angora Realms");
        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GameGUI g = new GameGUI();
        p.add(g);
        p.setSize(640, 800);
        p.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class GameGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        public Button drawCard = new Button("Draw Card");
        public Image cheetah = null;

        public GameGUI() {
            drawCard.addActionListener(this);
            add(drawCard);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            Object cause = event.getSource();

            if (cause == drawCard) {
                System.out.println("Ay");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawString("Hello", 200, 50);
            if (cheetah == null) {
                cheetah = getImage("plains/Cheetah.png");
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.drawImage(cheetah, 100, 100, 100, 300, this);
            }
        }

        public Image getImage(String path) {

            Image tempImage = null;
            try {
                URL imageURL = GameGUI.class.getResource(path);
                tempImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("An error occured -" + e.getMessage());
            }

            return tempImage;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've done all that, and it still doesnt seem to work, I even put a system.out underneath paintComponent and it doesn't print it, hmmm.